# css3 hover image slide, cant get it working properly

Tags: html, css

So the problem is the `#blue` wont change size when `#red` is hoverd but it works when `#green` is hoverd.

```
#red:hover +#blue{
    width:50px;
    transition:0.5s;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sAkRP/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `~` instead of `+` since `#blue` is not immediate next sibling of your `#red` here:

```
#red:hover ~#blue{
    width:50px;
    transition:0.5s;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAkRP/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change the `+` to `~`.

The plus only affect the next element. (Test it. Change the green element with the red element. So the red will work, the green not).

If you replace the `+` with `~`, it will affect all other ones.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JburC)